# Excel VBA Runtime Error 1004 when renaming ActiveSheet

Tags: vba, runtime-error, rename, concatenation

I'm at a loss when trying to figure out where this code is tripping up. I am looking to rename the activesheet by using a concat of two ranges on the activesheet and some static text. When only one worksheet is in the workbook, the code works great. As soon as a second worksheet is added, I get a Runtime Error 1004. I'll highlight the line of code where it is breaking. This code currently resides in a normal module.

```
Option Explicit
Sub updateName()
    Dim fNumber
    Dim pCheckNumber
    Dim asName As String
    Dim tempASName As String
    Dim worksheetName As Object

If ActiveSheet.Name = "Launch Page" Then Exit Sub

fNumber = ActiveSheet.Range("FlightNumber").Value
pCheckNumber = ActiveSheet.Range("PerformanceCheckNumber").Value

If fNumber <> "" And pCheckNumber <> "" Then
    tempASName = "Flight " & fNumber & " | Run " & pCheckNumber & " (0.0%)"
    asName = tempASName
    MsgBox ActiveSheet.Name & vbCr & asName
    ActiveSheet.Name = asName
    worksheetName.Caption = asName
Else
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

I'm in the process of adding error checking to ensure that I don't have duplicate sheet names. However, due to the nature of the field names, this will never occur.

I appreciate all of the insights!

Comment: So, where the code is breaking?

Comment: Could you add sample value of `asName` variable? there could be a character which is not allowed to use in sheet name or/and text could exceed length limit for sheet name.

Comment: Sorry, the code is breaking at the "if" statement - ActiveSheet.Name line. The value of asName in the above example would be "Flight 5 | Run 1 (0.0%). As far as I can tell, I am not using any prohibited characters and I'm within the 31 character limit.

Comment: fNumber and pCheckNumber are single digit integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are reporting is, most likely, provoked because of trying to rename a Worksheet by using a name already in use. Here you have a small code to avoid this kind of situations:

```
Dim newName As String: newName = "sheet1"
Dim addition As String: addition = "_2"
Do While (Not sheetNameFree(newName))
   newName = newName & addition
Loop
```

Where `sheetNameFree` is defined by:

```
Function sheetNameFree(curName As String) As Boolean
    sheetNameFree = True
    For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If (LCase(Sheet.Name) = LCase(curName)) Then
            sheetNameFree = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next Sheet
End Function
```

You can adapt this code to your specific needs (for example, by converting `addition` into a number which grows after each wrong name).

In your code I see one other problem (although it shouldn't be triggering a 1004 error): you are accessing the property `Caption` from an non-instantiated object (`worksheetName`), whose exact functionality is not too clear. Just delete this line.

NOTE: good point from KazJaw, you might be using an illegal character. If `fNumber` and `pCheckNumber` are numbers or letters, it would be OK.

NOTE2: if with `worksheetName` you want to refer to an `ActiveX Label` in your workSheet, better do: `ActiveSheet.Label1.Caption` (where `Label1` is the name of the Label). You cannot define  `worksheetName` as a Label, because it is not a "conventional Label".